# Command in Stata unrecognized

Tags: command, stata

I get the following error:

```
command center is unrecognized
```

Do I have to install something in Stata?

Comment: There is no command called `center` in Stata and you have not installed a custom command with that name. Please show code that triggers this error.

Comment: Explanation of edits https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-02/msg00429.html

Answer (score 1):

`center` is community-contributed (old jargon: user-written) and must be installed explicitly with

```
ssc install center
```